# How should I alter the question to make it more focused?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840557/how-to-investigate-the-reason-of-fail-generating-bundles-for-spa-in-net-core) that got closed due to not being more focused. I'd like to focus it more. However, I'm a bit stuck on how.

I've found [others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402177/how-can-i-make-my-question-more-focused) with similar concern, without any leads whatsoever, though.

I've considered posting some code but the issue is not code-wise, as it occurs in a vanilla setup. However, I suspect that it's not a well recognized issue as most of the devs start the project from the IDE and/or don't put much attention to warnings in the console unless there's an issue with the applications' behavior.

I'm fully prepared to investigate it deeper but since there's zero extra info, I'm prevented from proceeding, hence the question.

While I understand that *not sufficiently focused* is a generic term for a category, I still read into it that the reason for closing is that the question seems goofy and all over the place. I can't tell another user to be sensible and actually give me the benefit of doubt, as it'd be rather arrogant. Still, SO has been a bit cranky lately and waving off question prematurely (as they tend to get reopened frequently).

That being said, how do I increase focus in the linked question to allow others to provide me with support?

Answer (score 15):

I am not a domain expert on C# and .NET, but it strikes me that your question is lacking the kind of detail that would allow someone to figure out what is going on.  So I would (hypothetically ...) have voted to close it as either "Needs detail or clarity" or "Needs debugging details".

The fundamental point though is: don't get hung up over the specific closure reason (or reasons) that people have chosen.

Just try to figure out how you can make the question more "answerable".  For example, by providing a "recipe" which would allow someone with C#/.NET experience to *reproduce* what you are seeing.

> I still read into it that the reason for closing is that the question seems goofy and all over the place.

Well, that's not a correct reading of *any* of the Stack Overflow closure reasons.  There is really no point reading a closure vote or downvote as a personal putdown.  Votes are **just** votes.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is fine as it is, and I can see it's reopened now. At least with respect to "need focus". However, I can imagine that it should be closed for "needs clarity" or "needs debugging details" but I'm not an expert on C#.

However, very many use "focus" to close when they should have used "need clarity". That's because "focus" was previously called "too broad".

Comment: It's been closed again.

Answer (score 5):

I think that in general your question is fine and on-topic.

A few possible improvements:

- If I am not mistaken, you ask "how do I debug this", instead of "why does this happen". Since you are interested in investigating the issue yourself, asking this way kind of makes sense, but in my experience this kind of question is quite hard to answer in a definite way (there may not really be a generic debugging technique, and this would certainly be too broad).

  Perhaps you could slightly rewrite your question, so it asks for the reason of the issue itself? If you then later manage to solve the problem, and no one has answered yet, you can explain its cause in a self-answer. This will also help others who encounter the very same problem.
- As you state that this also occurs in a vanilla setup: Could you provide brief instructions on how to reproduce this problem? This may help others who look into that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Of the last 5 questions I asked that got closed, 4 were reopened. I argue that SO is too cranky lately (at least initially), hehe. I suspect that we're in a wave of premature closing: shoot first ask later, kind of. I'll try to rewrite the question but the steps will be 1. start a new web/angular project, 2. dotnet run. Somehow, I sense that if those instructions are needed, there won't be a useful input. But at least it proves some effort, I guess.

Comment: Well, even if reproducing an issue requires only two simple steps (which actually is great!), mentioning that in the question certainly doesn't harm. I am working with C#/.NET as well, and from the question it wasn't immediately obvious how to set up a suitable example project. Right now the question has two pending "Needs debugging details" close votes, probably for the same reason.

Comment: I just asked a new question and added "steps" for debug. Let's see if it helps. As for the *needs debugging details* that you mention, I'm not sure what more to provide. I can't shake off the sensation that people confuse ***this** can't be solved* and ***I** can't solve this*. But that's an arrogant though so I'm not going there. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Just because someone somewhere might see enough information in your question to answer it does not mean that the question is not lacking debugging details. No question could be voted as such otherwise. People can only vote to the best of their own knowledge.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm prone to agree with you. However, certain users should perhaps sustain from voting on certain issues. While you're perfectly correct - people vote in relation to **their** understanding of the matter. I guess, what I request, is a bit more modesty on their behalf. Often, them not understanding a question is less about said question and more about themselves. I mean, I don't walk around downing/closing Python questions just because I've done a project in Python but still don't understand the issue asked, hahaha. We need *you must be this tall to vote down*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sometimes for something that I know well I can take an educated guess at the problem from a vague description of an error message. That doesn't mean it's a good, complete question, or should not be closed. I'm not saying that's what here (because I haven't looked at your question), but it's possible

Comment: @DavidW Oh, I do agree with both your statements. I know precisely what you mean. And I can imagine if one sees such a gazillion times, one gets a bit disillusioned. I always invest time reading if I'm to pass a judgement just to make sure not to judge a book by its cover (nor the first or second chapter). But not everybody's got time. And I'm less efficient due to the time consumption.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You could argue that if people know enough, they should understand the problem and be able to answer it, but this doesn't always apply: certain questions about errors absolutely require clear reproduction steps to able to answer (e.g. null pointer exceptions). It's easier to have it as a general rule that almost anyone can understand and apply than to try to limit voting and closure (of the many, many, many questions we get) to the few domain experts we have. That is not to say those things are done particularly well in general, but I don't think this will make it better.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Reading your question, I can see one of a few possibilities: (1) this happens for basically every setup and any expert can answer it, (2) it happens for some setups, and a lot of experts can answer it, (3) it's quite obscure and few people reading it, if anyone, will have seen that before, much less know what it's about. From your question, it's not clear whether this happens for you for every project, some projects, one project or what, so you're mostly betting it's #1 or #2, but still details might help more people be able to answer it. For #3, details would be required.